# Extending the MVC RequiredAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

I have an extended class of RequiredAttribute that doesn't send error messages back. If I check it in the debugger the text is there alright.

```
public class VierRequired : RequiredAttribute
{
    public VierRequired(string controlName)
    {
        //...
    }

    public string VierErrorMessage
    {
        get { return ErrorMessage; }
        set { ErrorMessage = value; }
    }

    // validate true if there is any data at all in the object
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
            return true;

        return false; // base.IsValid(value);
    }
}
```

I call it like this

```
[VierRequired("FirstName", VierErrorMessage = "Please enter your first name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

And the mvc-view

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "formField textBox" })%>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)%>
```

It works if I use the normal Required annotation

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

But the custom does not send any error message back

Comment: Well, for one thing, your constructor doesn't have the same name as your class.  Was that just a transcription error?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't send error messages back"?

Comment: @Benjamin The error messages doesn't seem to be returned to the view. But if I use normal Required annotation they do.

Comment: I'm skeptical `value.ToString()` is actually doing what you think it is.  You need `value as String` instead.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I also had a problem with client side validation when I created my own derivative of the `RequiredAttribute`. To fix it you need to register your data annotation like so:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(
            typeof(VierRequired),
            typeof(RequiredAttributeAdapter));
```

Simply call this in your `Application_Start()` method and client side validation should work as normal.

If your attribute is not working when you are POST-ing your form then this would indicate to me that there is something wrong with the logic in your attribute (check you `IsValid` method).
I am also not sure what you are trying to achieve with your derived data annotation; your logic looks like it is trying to do pretty much what the default attribute does anyway:

Taken from the MSDN documentation:

> A validation exception is raised if the property is null, contains an empty string (""), or contains only white-space characters.

Comment: That is only required for client-side validation.

Comment: Turns out this was correct, my setup is somewhat complex since I run the mvc project inside another project.